# Java abstract class and overriding variables

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

I have encountered a problem which I cannot solve. Let's say we have the superclass A:

```
public enum Enumeration {
  A, B, C;
}

public abstract Class A {
     private Enumeration e;

     public void someMethod {
           // do something here with 'e'.
     }
}
```

Now let's assume we have an class B.

```
public Class B extends A {
    private final Enumeration = e.A;
}
```

Here I get a compiler warning that the value is never used.

I just want to define the method in Class A, thus I have to define the variable. But I want to give the variable a new fixed value in the subclass.

Is this not possible?

Comment: `private final Enumeration = e.A;` is missing a name.

Comment: `private final Enumeration = e.A;` looks like very clever code.

Comment: BTW, this is a `warning`, which means you can do it.

Comment: Are you saying that your child class inherits a `private` variable?

Comment: Fields don't "override", only methods do.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want.  If you want objects of class `B` to set `e` to some value, then put an assignment in the constructor for `B`, and make `e` `protected` instead of `private` so that the constructor can access it.  Or put a `protected` setter in `A` and let the constructor for `B` call it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't see how you get a warning.  I get `error: <identifier> expected` with `javac`.  Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: @ajb As per the OP `Here I get a compiler warning that the value is never used.`  I appreciate that he has other compile errors, but he is not asking about them.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Oh, I see.  I thought you tried it and were getting a warning on `private final Enumeration = e.A;`, which would be pretty bizarre.

Comment: @ajb Yep, too bizarre for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field can't be overridden. If you want to assign a specific enum instance to the class, use the constructor:

```
public abstract Class A {
     private final Enumeration e;

     protected A (Enumeration e) {
         this.e = e;
     }

     public void someMethod {
           // do something with 'e'.
     }
}

public Class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(Enumeration.A);
    }
}
```